# Possible to reference the key in the value of a key-value pair?

Tags: ruby

For example, say I want to do this:

```
{
  :mytime => times[:mytime]
}
```

There is a bit of repetition here, is it possible to just do something like `{ :mytime => times[$_key] }` (made up syntax)?

Comment: Why would you want to? I've never needed anything like that.

Comment: For formatting -- I have a lot of values, some of which may need special formatting (for example, time formatting or units).

Comment: That doesn't explain why. If you need special formatting you could handle it with a proc or lambda stored in the value and look it up by a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: no, there's no syntax that does anything like that.  Without more context about what you're actually trying to do, there isn't really a good longer answer.  Still, I'll try to be a little more useful.  If you're really worried about repetition, you could do something like:

```
h = {}
[:mytime, :yourtime].each do |k|
  h[k] = times[k]
end
```

For only a few keys, I can't see that being worth it, personally.

Comment: For a bit more context, I have an array of symbols which are keys to a hash of values. However, for certain keys the value may need special formatting such as adding units.